# Spring transaction propogation on non spring managed beans

Tags: spring, transactions

I am working on a migration project which involves upgrading the platform to Spring 4 with MyBatis. In the legacy code, transactions are handled at a central locations wherein call to start/end transactions are spread across various classes like service class, helper class and DAO class.

I managed to convert all service classes to spring managed component and DAO classes to support MyBatis-spring API. Problem is my service class use several other classes to perform a function and those classes are all instantiated manually and used. Now if i start a transaction on service class methods and perform database transactions inside other helper or DAO classes which are not spring managed, my transaction handling doesn't work correctly. I have illustrated this problem in the below code. Could you tell what are the ways to acheive transaction handling without modifying the code?

Example :

```
    package com.service;

    @Service
    class MyService {

        @Transactional( propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void processRequest () {
            HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();
            helper.performOperation();
        }
    }

    package com.helper;

    // this class is not spring bean
    class HelperClass {

        // MyBatis mapper class
        private EmployeeMapper mapper;

        public HelperClass () {
            mapper = // retrieve mapper class bean from spring context
        }

        public performOperation () {
            // call to mapper class insert operation
            // call to mapper class update operation
        }
    }

    package com.dao;
    @Component
    interface EmployeeMapper {
        // method definition to perform database operation
    }
```

**Spring configuration details:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    ....
    ....
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />

<mybatis:scan base-package="com.dao" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mapperLocations"
        value="classpath*:mybatis/*.xml" />
</bean>
```

In the above code HelperClass.performOperation() method is doing 2 database operations (insert,update). Say if insert succeeds and update fails, my database transaction doesn't get rollback. Since I already started the transaction at MyService.processRequest() should this not rollback the operations that are carried inside that method call? Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: How is the `mapper` retrieved from the spring context? Also why aren't you just injecting the `HelperClass`?

Comment: Mapper classes are retrieved from class that implements BeanFactoryAware interface. Basically reading from BeanFactory object. I can inject HelperClass to Service, but there are lot many classes like that which i have to modify.

Comment: If you are using the same context to retrieve the beans from then you must be doing something incorrect in your data access code.

Comment: Hi Deinum, things work fine if I convert Helperclass to spring managed bean and add @Transactional annotation to helper class method. But, since I have more classes like that, I wanted to know is there any other way to achieve same result without making HelperClass as spring bean

Comment: Generally you want to make it a spring bean, however if it works it should also work with the setup you have now. Hence I wonder if your `@Transactional` on the service is actually doing something... Please add some configuration and more code of the `HelperClass` to your question.

Comment: Added spring configuration details to my question. There is nothing much under helperclass code as it simply calls mapper class methods to perform DB operation. As mapper class implementation is dynamically generated by MyBatis code we have only interface definitions whose methods directly map to sql query which are defined under XML files

Comment: Why are you using `mode='aspectj` for your `<tx:annotation-driven />`. Do you have load or compile time weaving in place? If not you basically are running without transactions.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I was just trying if that will help. Even if I remove that attribute it doesn't work.